# Adding Items to ListBox Asynchronously

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am working on adding items to a ListBox, `uxSearchList`. However, even though **the code behind works as expected**, the changes do not reflect within the `uxSearchList` ListBox after clicking `Search`.

I do the following:

- Enter search criteria (`uxEsnCheck/Text`, `uxLocationList/Text`)
- Click on `Search`
- (in progress) Populate search results into `uxSearchList`

How do I populate the `uxSearchList` ListBox through what I currently have? My code is below.

---

**.ASPX.CS**

```
    protected void uxSearchParams_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uxSearchList.Items.Clear();

        var selectedSerial = uxEsnText.Text;
        var selectedLocation = uxLocationList.Text;

        if (!uxEsnText.Enabled)
        {
            selectedSerial = string.Empty;
        }
        if (!uxLocationList.Enabled)
        {
            selectedLocation = string.Empty;
        }

        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            var selectedParams = _presenter.OnSelectionParams(selectedSerial, selectedLocation);

            foreach (var param in selectedParams)
            {
                uxSearchList.Items.Add(param.SerialNumber);
            }
        }
    }
```

**.ASPX**

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uxParamsPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="uxEsnCheck" runat="server" CssClass="form-label" Text="Engine Serial Number" OnCheckedChanged="uxEsnCheck_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="uxEsnText" runat="server" Enabled="False"/>

                <asp:CheckBox ID="uxLocationCheck" runat="server" CssClass="form-label" Text="Location" OnCheckedChanged="uxLocationCheck_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="uxLocationList" runat="server" Enabled="False"/>

                <asp:Button ID="uxSearchParams" runat="server" onclick="uxSearchParams_Click" CssClass="form-label" Text="Search" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxSearchParams" EventName="Click" />

                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxEsnCheck" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxLocationCheck" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uxSelectionPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="uxSearchDisplay" runat="server" CssClass="form-label" Text="Search Results" />
                <asp:ListBox ID="uxSearchList" runat="server" Width="250px" />

                <asp:Label ID="uxMemberDisplay" runat="server" CssClass="form-label" Text="Engine Group Members" />
                <asp:ListBox ID="uxMemberList" runat="server" Width="250px" />

                <asp:Button ID="uxAdd" runat="server" onclick="uxAdd_Click" Text=">" />
                <asp:Button ID="uxRemove" runat="server" onclick="uxRemove_Click" Text="<" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxAdd" EventName="Click" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxRemove" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: If it works "as expected", how come the result is incorrect? What exactly goes wrong in your opinion, is the search result not the one you expect?

Comment: The search result is good. I step through and saw that items are being added to **uxSearchList.Items** ***as expected*** in the code-behind. However, it does not present itself in **uxSearchList**. I expect to see several items inside the **uxSearchList** ListBox after I click on **uxSearchParams**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have better results using the databinding methods. Using the following class I was able to get the results to show correctly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test.Web
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private readonly IList<string> database;
        private string currentSearch;

        public Test()
        {
            database = new List<string>();
            database.Add("hello");
            database.Add("world");
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            uxSearchList.DataBinding += dataBindSearch;
        }

        protected void OnSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentSearch = searchText.Text;
            uxSearchList.DataBind();
        }

        private void dataBindSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IList<string> results = new List<string>();
            foreach (string item in database)
            {
                if (item.StartsWith(currentSearch))
                {
                    results.Add(item);
                }
            }
            uxSearchList.DataSource = results;
        }
    }
}
```

The main difference is that I'm using `DataSource` instead of the `Items` collection, and call DataBind on the list when the search query has changed.

If this change does not work for you, you might have another problem with the markup. I'm simply binding the OnTextChanged event, but nothing more.

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="searchText" OnTextChanged="OnSearch" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uxSelectionPanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="uxSearchDisplay" runat="server" CssClass="form-label" Text="Search Results" />
            <asp:ListBox ID="uxSearchList" runat="server" Width="250px" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click search you are updating the list on the server side of things.  You need to provide a way for the client side to update.  I see that the uxSearchList is inside of an UpdatePanel.  I'm not too good with these, but I would try and add additional triggers to this.  This way, when the contents of the uxSearchList changes, the client facing display is also updated.

Comment: I've added additional triggers to the listboxes to no avail. Do you have any rough examples on how to achieve this?

Comment: There are several On (OnSelectedText, OnTextChanged, etc.) functions, but do any of them fit what I'm doing for listboxes?

Comment: I haven't used an UpdatePanel before sadly, but I have found a link online that explains them in further detail.

http://www.netrostar.com/How-to-Use-NET-Update-Panel

The fundamental problem is you need to update the client with the updated server side data.  I typically use Javascript and control my own ajax calls, but here the Update Panel takes care of this.